# Automatically fit image to window (OpenCV 2.4, OS X)

Tags: macos, opencv

I am trying to automatically fit the size of an image to the window it is displayed in, so that the image will change it size whenever I change the size of the window.

Is there a way to do this using the OpenCV HighGUI? If this is a OS individual task, does anyone know how to do it in OS X?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the width and height of your window and rescale your image using resize function - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize I don't think that it's possible to get the size of window using only OpenCV, most likely you will need to use OS specific API or Qt(if you are using OpenCV with QT - yes it's possible and it's quite good idea if you need to make nice GUI - here you have more informations: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html probably setWindowsProperty is the function you are looking for. Installation instruction - ).

Note - i'm not sure whether it's possible to resize window created by OpenCV. If not and you are using Qt, you need to call qt function setwindowproperty and set `CV_WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE` to `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL`.

Comment: Yes, the OpenCV windows can be resized if you don't create them with CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE. Qt is a good hint, I will take a look at it. Thank you.